# iPhone: Is there a way to exit from the MPMoviePlayerController before the video ends?

Tags: ios, video

I have a app that plays video.  Right now it exits when the vedio has finished by using the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotificatio notification.  The only way to stop the vedio right now is to fast forward it so the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotificatio notification. goes off.  Is there a way to had e a button or something  cause it to exit?  I tried putting a button on in the ui editor, but it did not show up, the video player covered it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the fullscreen control style, you'll get a DONE button that you can press to exit the video.

Check out the controlStyle property and the MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen constant.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html